# Configurable workflow engine for ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow, workflow-activity

I want to use a user configurable workflow engine for an ASP.NET application. The workflow engine should provide a web based graphical designer for the end user and an API for integrating the workflow designed by the end user graphically. Does anyone have a suggestion for .Net based open source configurable workflow engines or a commercial products?

Answer (score 1):

I've used both Windows Workflow Foundation ([WF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx)) and [K2.net](http://www.k2.com/en/index.aspx) (which I guess they now call blackpearl).  Both are excellent, neither is open source, K2 is a bit spendy.

Comment: Hi JP, Thanks for the reply. I want a graphical workflow designer for the customer. Please let me know the price of K2 if you know.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I have not priced out k2 recently.